# cannot deploy scrapy spider on the cloud(zyte) : AttributeError: 'ScrapyArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'add_option'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to deploy the spider crawler I made, the code is working fine on my computer and when I try to deploy it to https://app.zyte.com/, in order to run it on the cloud I get this error:

```
warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
Packing version 1.0
Deploying to Scrapy Cloud project "615653"
Deploy log last 30 lines:

Deploy log location: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\shub_deploy_4a5i8o6z.log

    Error: Deploy failed: b'{"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}'
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 148, in _run_usercode
        _run(args, settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 103, in _run
        _run_scrapy(args, settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 111, in _run_scrapy
        execute(settings=settings)
      File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
        cmd.add_options(parser)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/commands/shub_image_info.py", line 23, in add_options
        parser.add_option("--debug", action="store_true",
    AttributeError: 'ScrapyArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'add_option'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/shub-image-info", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(shub_image_info())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 209, in shub_image_info
        _run_usercode(None, ['scrapy', 'shub_image_info'] + sys.argv[1:],
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 148, in _run_usercode
        _run(args, settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 103, in _run
        _run_scrapy(args, settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 111, in _run_scrapy
        execute(settings=settings)
      File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
        cmd.add_options(parser)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh_scrapy/commands/shub_image_info.py", line 23, in add_options
        parser.add_option("--debug", action="store_true",
    AttributeError: 'ScrapyArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'add_option'
    {"message": "shub-image-info exit code: 1", "details": null, "error": "image_info_error"}
    {"status": "error", "message": "Internal error"}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a first look it looks like it.. may be result of difference between stack parameter defined in `scrapinghub.yml` file and version of scrapy used in Your project.

It is expected that defined stack should match used scrapy version.

More info about scrapy cloud stacks ([docs](https://support.zyte.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200402-changing-the-deploy-environment-with-scrapy-cloud-stacks)).

Comment: It worked for me I was using Scrapy2.8 and put `stacks:
  default: scrapy:2.8`